# Image files organizer for OS X

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, macos

Is there a good image file organizer for OS X?

I'm looking for something with good previews for image files, and that will allow me to tag the files.

Comment: Will the built-in (and hence, free) iPhoto app not work for your purpose?  If not, please provide more detail in your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**I use [Adobe Bridge](http://www.adobe.com/products/bridge.html)**, which comes with lots of Adobe apps ([list](http://www.adobe.com/products/bridge/buying-guide.html), starting at $250).
It does all you want, and a lot of other stuff too.

Some of my favorite features, other than those that you mentioned:

- Full-screen previews
- Powerful batch renaming
- Cache export
- Configurability / flexibility
- Speed

Another option is [Adobe Lightroom](http://tryit.adobe.com/us/cs5/lightroom) ($250). It combines a Bridge-like manager with a reasonably-powerful editor.

---

I realize that Bridge and Lightroom certainly aren't free, but Bridge really is my favorite image manager.

If you want something that's free, the built-in iPhoto app is a good option, although it's far less powerful. It's got some nice features like face recognition and location-based sorting.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) meets most of the requirements you are mentioning - preview, tagging (it is excellent in identifying faces, so listing photos of a person in hundreds of photos is pretty easy with picasa).

However if you are looking for an organizer of both photos & images then [Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom.html) is the choice. It is not free but productivity gain easily compensates its price.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/mac/)? It's free and can manage many image types and it does all that quite efficiently. There are several advantages and disadvantages which I'm sure you can find out by searching in the net but here is a comparison [iPhoto vs. Picasa](http://macifyme.com/blog/?p=119). The choice is your as always:)